# How to craft Invalid packet to test for TLS Poodle vulnerability?

Tags: tls, vulnerability

I need to test if a server is vulnerable to TLS Poodle.
To do this I need to send an invalid packet to the server and check if it closes the connection.
But I am not sure how I create that packet (request).
What should go in it?

Comment: Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31721567/how-to-test-poodle-over-tls

Comment: I don't know how the POODLE vulnerability works. However, you might want to take a look at [Scapy.](http://secdev.org/projects/scapy/) It allows you to craft you own packets, valid of invalid.